# SwiftUI and data models (CoreData) - How to changing data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, binding, swiftui

I'm extremely confused on how to use `Core Data` with `SwiftUI`. There are tons of articles about it but everyone's only showcasing crafted situations that work perfectly. Nobody's showing slightly more complicated stuff and I can't figure it out. I've been trying for two weeks. (I *am* able to code it in order to get it to simply work; However, I'm trying to find a good and pragmatic way and that's what I'm struggling with).

Here's an example:

```swift
struct CarView: View {
    @State var car: Car

    struct Car {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let name: String
        let price: Int
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(car.name)
            Text("\(car.price)")
        }
    }
}


struct CarView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CarView(car: .init(name: "Tesla Model X", price: 42))
    }
}
```

This is a perfectly simple construct that's also easily testable and handleable because you can simply create a dummy `Car` instance to use XCode Previews, for instance.

But what happens if you want to add a data model to it that's pulling data from a database? Say you have a `CarManagedObject` `NSManagedObject` subclass. How would you connect that to our `SwiftUI` View?

You could simply replace the `Car` struct with `CarManagedObject` subclass because it conforms to `ObservableObject`. So something like this would work:

```swift
struct CarView: View {
    @ObservedObject var car: CarManagedObject
    ...
}
```

However, now we've tightly coupled the `CarView` with `Core Data`. You cannot use the view without it anymore. It's also a pain to create dummy data. So it would be better to keep using a `Car` struct that's independent of everything. This is also what Apple is doing in session 233 of WWDC 2019 starting at about minute 37: [Session 23, WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/233/).

So you could do this:

```swift
struct Car {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let price: Int

    static func create(from: CarManagedObject) -> Car {
        ...
    }
}
```

This all works well until you have data that can change. I don't see a good way of keeping the struct updated when the underlying data changes. Also, we entirely lose the ability to pass `Bindings` down to subviews because the `Car` struct is not the actual data source. Changing it does not change the data model.

You could painfully set it up using `Combine` in both directions but that doesn't seem right. I'm sure `SwiftUI` is capable of doing this, I just don't see how.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?
Sorry if it's not entirely clear what I mean. I'm really confused. All this kind of breaks my head :D

Comment: Did anybody find a good solution for this? I have basically the exact same question. I’ve been using Core Data directly and that doesn’t work so great for all of the reasons mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I found your question while searching for even more basic answers to my own. Having not found anything here, I carried on searching and came across this Apple documentation page which I think might answer your question. However, I am unqualified (at this time) to say it does.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: Appreciate the answer, unfortunately the article is just about general data management in SwiftUI, not a methodical suggestion on how to handle synchronization between CoreData and SwiftUI structs